# how to convert Scala List of bytes to blob

Tags: scala, cassandra, playframework-2.6

My schema uses a `blob` type

```
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    a  text,
    d  text,
    h  list<text>,
    i list<blob>,
    p  text,
    t  set<text>,
    title text
```

I send a `json` fromm client which gets converted into a case class and then I use the case class in QueryBuilder. In `json`, I am sending a `string` for the property which will be stored as a `blob` and I want to convert the `string` into `blob` when inserting into Cassandra. But I don't know how to do so.

`json` is `PracticeQuestion(Some(2b01be60-6210-4449-ad40-6b97297d69f2),d,List(d),List(List(1)),d,Set(d),d,d)`

`case class` is

```
case class Data (id: Option[UUID],
                              d : String, //text in cassandra
                              h : List[String], //list <text>
                              i : List[Seq[Byte]], //list<blob>. 
                              p : String,//string
                              t : Set[String], //set<text>
                              title : String, // text
                              a:String ) //text
```

The `QueryBuilder` code is

```
def  insertValues(tableName:String, model:PracticeQuestion):Insert = {
    QueryBuilder.insertInto(tableName).value("id",model.id.get)
      .value("a",model.a)
      .value("d",model.d)
      .value("h",seqAsJavaList(model.h)) 
      .value("image",seqAsJavaList(model.image)) //this probably isn't correct.
      .value("p",model.p)
      .value("t",setAsJavaSet(model.t))
      .value("title",model.title)
      .ifNotExists();       }
```

When I run my code, I get the following error `Errorcom.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Value 4 of type class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$SeqWrapper does not correspond to any CQL3 type`

Comment: While inserting the image you are doing seqAsJavaLiat but you should do blobAsByte(x) data type List[Seq[byte]] is not supported by Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks. It seems `blobAsByte` doesn't exist in `Cassandra 3.0`. Also, I changed the schema to `i: Seq[Byte]`. So `model.i` should be `Seq[Byte]` now. How do I convert `Seq[Byte]` to `blob`?

Comment: Then do blobAsBigInt it exists

Comment: which file I need to import for these methods? I have imported `scala.collection.JavaConverters._` but can't see `blogAsBigInt`

Comment: Also the names of the methods seem to suggest they convert from `blob` to some other data type. I need to convert to blob, not from it as my cassandra schema is `i <blob>`.

Comment: I could make it work by changing my schema. The field in `case class` to store `i` is `Array[Byte]` and I used `Bytebuffer.wrap` to convert the `Array[Byte] to `ByteBuffer` i.e. `ByteBuffer.wrap(model.i)`. Your comment about changing the schema was helpful. I'll be happy to accept your answer if you convert the comment into answer.

Comment: Actually that import Scala.collection.JavaConverters is for all the methods that are used to change java data types to Scala dada types. And you need to insert List[Byte] into cassandra but Cassandra only supports primitive data type and they added new feature in 3.0 version blob which is the hexadecimal number. Now the problem is you need to change your List[Byte]. Please refer this https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/blob_r.html

Comment: Are these CQL commands or Datastax driver commands? The example seems to indicate that these work only on CQL. I have anyhow changed the schema to Array[Byte]

Comment: They must have something equivalent in dataStax driver because they officially support Cassandra so!! Idk but there should be something sorry but I don’t have that much knowledge.

Comment: And if you can use the prepared Statement then I think there would be something when we need to set the value in the prepared statement so there should be something like setBlob(value), BoundStatemebt has a method called setList that will work for you. Please refer this if that work let me know so I can Answer with that https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/BoundStatement.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you can do is to change your table scheme. Because Cassandra doesn’t support data type Seq[List[Bytes]].

If that’s not possible you can try the following.

The problem is that Cassandra doesn’t support the `List[Byte]` so it has the data type blob which actually accept the hexadecimal value. As you have the Array of bytes and you need to set it as value for your 4th field, I would suggest you to use BoundStatements which has the method `setList(yourList)` this way you can Set Value for your preparedStatement.

You can do something like this.

```
BoundStatement bound = ps1.bind()

bound.setList(yourList[Byte])

session.execute(bound)
```

You can refer to this:

> https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.0/manual/statements/prepared/