# How to convert ByteBuffer to blob for cassandra insertion?

Tags: scala, cassandra, blob, bytebuffer

I have a `java.nio.ByteBuffer`, which I need to pass to a Cassandra table that has a field as a blob.

Here is the relevant code for a toy example:

```
  val ww = "65984jg3oiqh4g3q383423932824344"
  val www = getBytes(ww)
  val wwww = LongTupleHashFunction.xx128().hashBytes(www)
  val wwwww = ByteBuffer.allocate(128).putLong(wwww(0)).putLong(wwww(1))
  wwwww.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)

  val d_q = "DROP TABLE example.test "
  val t_q = "CREATE TABLE example.test (hash_aggregation_key blob, PRIMARY KEY (hash_aggregation_key)) "

  cassandraSession.execute(d_q)
  cassandraSession.execute(t_q)

  val ps: PreparedStatement = cassandraSession.prepare("insert into " + Constants.FEATURE_KEYSPACE + "." +
    Constants.FEATURE_TABLE + "(hash_aggregation_key) VALUES(?) USING TTL 100000")
  val bStatement: BoundStatement = ps.bind
  bStatement.setList("hash_aggregation_key",wwwww)
  cassandraSession.execute(bStatement)
```

This stackoverflow said to use "setList": [how to convert Scala List of bytes to blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51028972/how-to-convert-scala-list-of-bytes-to-blob)

But I don't have a list of bytes, I have a ByteBuffer. Also, another issue is that it tells me `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'setList'`.

This StackOverflow seemed like it would answer my question, but hilariously enough they don't actually have any cassandra code in here it's all about the wrappings: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32556/storing-a-bytebuffer-into-a-cassandra-database

I THINK this might have what I'm looking for, but I'm having trouble finding where they actually convert and insert a blob: https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/blobs-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/examples/BlobsApp.java

EDIT: I found this, https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1325?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Which seems to be implying I should use setBytes. However, I still get the `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'setBytes'` error, so I'm confused as to what's causing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact solution may depend on the version of the driver used ([3.x](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.8/com/datastax/driver/core/BoundStatement.html#setBytes-java.lang.String-java.nio.ByteBuffer-) vs [4.x](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.11/manual/core/statements/prepared/)).

In the simplest case you just need to do (specify all arguments when calling `.bind`):

```
val bStatement: BoundStatement = ps.bind(wwwww)
cassandraSession.execute(bStatement)
```

Or you can use [`.setBytes` function](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.8/com/datastax/driver/core/BoundStatement.html#setBytes-java.lang.String-java.nio.ByteBuffer-) (in 3.x) if you want to bind by name:

```
val bStatement: BoundStatement = ps.bind
bStatement.setBytes("hash_aggregation_key",wwwww)
cassandraSession.execute(bStatement)
```

or [`.setByteBuffer` function](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.11/) (in 4.x) - notice that it doesn't do in-place assignment but returns a new instance:

```
val bStatement: BoundStatement = ps.bind.setByteBuffer("hash_aggregation_key",wwwww)
cassandraSession.execute(bStatement)
```